# JQuery - Ajax return HTML wont allow further Jquery functions?

Tags: ajax, jsp

Kinda New to Jquery and hit an issue regarding returned HTML.  I am using the .load() function to load HTML returned from a jsp file - its all working grand except the returned HTML doesnt seem to allow further Jquery functions to be called on it.

i have a click and toggle combination running for "#showgame" - this id is in the returned HTML but clicking on it does nothing when it should.  Do i have to update anything to tell jquery that this id now exists on the page after load() call?

Regards,

Cormac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `live()` function to bind the click event.

```
$("#myelement").live("click", function() { });
```

Live binds the event to current and *future* elements that match the selector.

Read more at http://api.jquery.com/live .